# Single Sign On with OpenID for Google Apps Marketplace App: openid_identifier parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openid, single-sign-on, google-apps-marketplace

I've created an App for the Google Apps Marketplace and need to integrate Single Sign On with OpenID. After installing the App, the link to our App is:

https://www.my_app.com/users/auth/google?from=google&domain=my_app.com

To use this [ruby-openid](https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid/blob/master/examples/rails_openid/app/controllers/consumer_controller.rb) library I need an openid_identifier parameter

```
identifier = params[:openid_identifier]
```

However, I can't seem to find how I get this openid_identifier after the redirect from Google Apps. Am I missing something here?

Comment: We (Google) have released a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace ([see announcement](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html)). In the new experience, we have moved away from OpenID and rely only on OAuth2. You can read details in our [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/).